# Python: Too much space between printing lines read from a text file

Tags: python, list, file, read-write

I have this little problem.
 If i create a list from the content of a txt file and print it row by row there are huge spaces between these outputs.

**Like:**

Name

Name

Street

**Thats how i want to style it:**

Name
Name
Street

**And this is the code:**

```
import os.path

print('Get User Data')
print()
vName = input('Vorname:   ')
nName = input('Nachname:  ')


data = [vName, nName]

if os.path.isfile('data/'+vName+'_'+nName+'.txt'):
    file = open('data/'+vName+'_'+nName+'.txt', 'r')
    content = file.readlines()
    for element in content:
        print(element)
else:
    data.append(input('Straße/Nr.:'))
    file = open('data/'+vName+'_'+nName+'.txt', 'w')
    for row in data:
        file.write(row)
    print()
    print('New File created. --> /data/'+vName+'_'+nName+'.txt')

file.close()
```

Can someone explain why this happens and how to fix it?
Thank you :)

Comment: strip the strings before printing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to strip the new line character, `\n`, before you print.

`element.strip('\n')` will get the job done.

```
if os.path.isfile('data/'+vName+'_'+nName+'.txt'):
    file = open('data/'+vName+'_'+nName+'.txt', 'r')
    content = file.readlines()
    for element in content:
        element = element.strip('\n') # this is the line we add to strip the newline character
        print(element)
```

Comment: Thank you Harrison!

Comment: No problem! Hope I was able to help you! :)

Comment: This doesn't work. `.strip()` cannot modify the string. You'd need `element=element.strip('\n')` instead.

Comment: @viraptor Oops, forgot that `strip()` returns a copy of the string. Fixed that :) Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

Related to [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-in-python-without-newline-or-space): *if you don't want to alter your input*, you can stop print from adding a newline.

> In Python 3, the print statement has been changed into a function. In Python 3, you can instead do:

```
 print('.', end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

When your read in the lines of the file, each contains a character at the end to skip to a new line (a newline character).  When you print each of these, `print` also adds one, so that you now have an extra blank line between each "real" line.  The solution, as @FamousJameous pointed out, is to use `strip` to remove the newline character from the string before printing it.

Answer (score -1):

```
for a in list(range(9)):
    print(a, file=open('file.txt', 'a'))
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.